# IE9 onclick Bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

```
this.fillSelectBox  = function (flowCounterObj)
{
    while (this.selectBox.hasChildNodes())
    {
        this.selectBox.removeChild(this.selectBox.firstChild);
    }
    var line = 0;
    for(line = 0; line < this.lines.length; line++)
    {
        var newOption = document.createElement('option');
        newOption.setAttribute('value','line_' + line);
        newOption.innerHTML = 'Line ' + line;
        newOption.onclick = function(){flowCounterObj.setCurrentLine(this.index);};
        this.selectBox.appendChild(newOption);
    }
};
```

The above code removes all options from the select box and the creates a new option for each line I have in my array.

It adds a event to the onclick.

When I select my options in Chrome they call the setCurrentLine() function.  However in IE9 it doesn't.

I have looked at the debugging windows in both IE9 and Chrome and they apply the same stuff.

I have tried using `setAttribute('onclick',flowCounter.setCurrentLine('+line+');');` but that doesn't work either in IE9 (does in Chrome);

I have also tried using `addEventListener(...);` but that doesn't work in IE9 (does in Chrome).

(On a side note should I actually be using addEventListener for this? Is that the correct way?)

I put the code through JS lint and it says I shouldn't create functions in loops?

Any ideas? Do you think this could actually be a bug?

Matt

**EDIT**:  I tried the following HTML code in IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <select id='lineSelect' size='4'>
        <option value='line_1' onclick='alert("whoop");'>Line 1</option>
        <option value='line_2' onclick='alert("whoop");'>Line 2</option>
        <option value='line_3' onclick='alert("whoop");'>Line 3</option>
        <option value='line_4' onclick='alert("whoop");'>Line 4</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

And that doesn't do anything?  Does in chrome/safari/firefox/opera! Also did it with onClick/onChange.

Comment: Do you have a doctype defined in your webpage? The IE9 Document Mode is only used when a doctype is used or it is forced. (I'm not sure if this includes Javascript though, so I could be wrong here)

Comment: In IE you should be using `attachEvent` not `addEventListener` (your 3rd test)  It's possible IE is being case picky too... the event name (and so attribute) is [onClick](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/event2.shtml)

Comment: Why don't you use the `onclick` or `onchange` event of the selectbox instead?

Comment: I have a DOCTYPE.
I looked at the onClick, but in the DOM in IE9 debugging its onclick and also in chrome - so i wasn't sure.
onchange on the selectbox is a much better idea.

Comment: Look at this [link](http://www.ozzu.com/website-design-forum/option-onclick-internet-explorer-t55560.html), it seems like it might have to do with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and it seems that an `option` doesn't have an `onclick` event. However, it does have a `onselect` or `onchange` event.

I think using the `onclick` or `onchange` event of the selectbox itself is the best solution in this case.

Comment: I agree. Only event to use in a select is the onchange of the select itself

Comment: How did you determine that "`option` doesn't have an `onclick`" from that msdn page? Is it documentation by omission? (I'm not questioning the fact, just interested in how to actually get use out of msdn content)

Comment: @Stephen - I just looked at the msdn page, and it seems they changed it completely. This is how it used to look like: http://web.archive.org/web/20100921202621/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877(v=VS.85).aspx This version contains a complete list of all the supported events.

Comment: Well that explains a lot. It sounds similar to lots of things I've heard about MS Metro - "it's much simpler!"

Answer (score 0):

Also note that from IE9 onwards, onclick is not working anymore.
Is **onClick** "case sensitive"